# How can i perform Cosinor analysis in Matlab?

Tags: time-series, dataset, matlab, spectral-analysis, cosinor

I have monthly and daily data from births in Greece and I want to perform a cosinor analysis to find the rhythm, (circadian, circannual, half yearly, etc.)

How can I use Matlab to perform the cosinor analysis?
I found [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20329-cosinor-analysis/content/html/cosinor.html) but not sure if it can help.

Is there anything else that i could do with these data apart from cosinor analysis? I did a fourier spectral analysis and found a strong 12 month cycle and a strong 2 month cycle.